# How to compare unichar from a buffer?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to compare unichar, but my code below doesn't work.

```
NSString *str = @"some string ^ ^";
NSUInteger len = [str length];
unichar buffer[len+1];
[str getCharacters:buffer range:NSMakeRange(0, len)];
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (buffer[i] == '^') NSLog(@"%C", buffer[i]);
}
```

It doesn't seem to be able to log the `^` even though it exist. Any idea why?

Comment: I think you get only the first few chars as the buffer length and the string length will differ. As a test, try to pu the carets first and see what happens. If that is it you need to determine the length differently e.g. using ```rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange```.

Comment: I tried your code and `^` is logged twice.